# Given an exact date, time, and coordinate, can I locate a plane that flew overhead?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I need to identify an aircraft seen at 36.841900,-87.673600 Kentucky on July 4, 2020, at 12:29am.

Is there a way to do this feasibly?
[image]

Figured out what it is:
[image]

Comment: Is this not the same as your previous question?

Comment: @ThatCoolCoder - that could be said, but no I asked a new set of questions. Check the update.

Comment: Voting to close THAT question as a duplicate of this one. This is the better question, and there is no need for both to be open.

Comment: Your “figured out what it is” remark isn’t appropriate to include in the question.  If you like you can post a separate self answer that includes this information for the curious.  And choose your own answer as accepted.  P.S.  given your description in the other question, this calls into question your powers of observation...

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/). In addition to its many other features, it has a playback mode. I'm not sure if there is a simple way to view a specific coordinate; however it should be easy enough to navigate to your desired location using the map view. If looking at coordinates is a must, I have found that you can put them after the url like so:

`https://www.flightradar24.com/-36.38,128.09`

**Edit**

According to Jan Hudec, you need a flightradar24 subscription to access dates this old.

Comment: You'll need a subscription with a date that old though. For free, the playback only goes back 7 days.

Comment: If the spotting was close enough to an airport, [https://webtrak.emsbk.com](https://webtrak.emsbk.com) would have shown it, but unfortunately the playback only goes back two months there.